# Use Dropwizard configuration in a method that establishes a connection to a MongoDB database

Tags: java, mongodb, dropwizard, mongodb-java

I am coding Dropwizard micro-services that fetch data in a MongoDB database. The micro-services work fine but I'm struggling to use in my DAO the configuration coming from my Dropwizard configuration Java class. Currently I have

```
public class XDAO implements IXDAO {

    protected DB db;
    protected DBCollection collection;

    /* singleton */
    private static XDAO instance;

    /* Get singleton */
    public static synchronized XDAO getSingleton(){
       if (instance == null){
         instance = new XDAO();
       }       
      return instance;
    }

    /* constructor */
    public XDAO(){
       initDatabase();
       initDatabaseIndexes();
    }

    private void initDatabase(){
       MongoClient client = null;

       try {
           client = new Mongo("10.126.80.192",27017); 
           db = client.getDB("terre");
           //then some other code
       }

       catch (final MongoException e){
         ...
       }

       catch (UnknownHostException e){
         ...
       }

     }

 }
```

I want to unhard-code the three arguments in these two lines :

```
  client = new Mongo("10.126.80.192", 27017); 
  db = client.getDB("terre");
```

My MongoConfiguration Java class is :

```
public class MongoConfiguration extends Configuration {

@JsonProperty
@NotEmpty
public String host;

@JsonProperty
public int port = 27017;

@JsonProperty
@NotEmpty
public String db_name;

public String getMongohost() {
    return host;
}

public void setMongohost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}

public int getMongoport() {
    return port;
}

public void setMongoport(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public String getDb_name() {
    return db_name;
}

public void setDb_name(String db_name) {
    this.db_name = db_name;
}

}
```

My Resource class that uses the DAO is :

```
@Path("/mongo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {

private XDAO xDAO = XDAO.getSingleton();

private String mongohost;
private String db_name;
private int mongoport;

public MyResource(String db_name, String mongohost, int mongoport) {
    this.db_name = db_name;
    this.mongohost = mongohost;
    this.mongoport = mongoport;
}

public MyResource() {
}

@GET
@Path("/findByUUID")
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
public Entity findByUUID(@QueryParam("uuid") String uuid) {

    return xDAO.findByUUid(uuid);
  }
}
```

And in my application class there is

```
  @Override
  public void run(final MongoConfiguration configuration, final Environment environment) {

    final MyResource resource = new MyResource(configuration.getDb_name(), configuration.getMongohost(), configuration.getMongoport());
    environment.jersey().register(resource);
   }
```

To solve my problem I tried many things. The last thing I tried was to add these four fields in my XDAO

```
  private String mongohost;
  private String db_name;
  private int mongoport;
  private static final MongoConfiguration configuration = new MongoConfiguration();
```

Coming with this piece of code in the constructor of the XDAO:

```
public XDAO(){
    instance.mongohost = configuration.getMongohost();
    instance.mongoport = configuration.getMongoport();
    instance.db_name = configuration.getDb_name();
    /* then like before */
    initDatabase();
    initDatabaseIndexes();
}
```

When I try this I have a null pointer exception when my initDatabase method is invoked : mongoHost and db_name are null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a *new* configuration in your XDAO with `private static final MongoConfiguration configuration = new MongoConfiguration();` instead of using the config from Dropwizard's `run` method.

When you do this, the fields `host` and `db_name` in the *new* configuration are null, which is why you are getting the NPE when instantiating `XDAO`

You need to pass the instance of `MongoConfiguration` that you get from Dropwizard in your application class to your `XDAO`, ideally when the singleton `XDAO` is created so it has non-null values for `db_name` and `host`

This code below part of the problem - you are creating the singleton without giving `XDAO` the `MongoConfiguration` configuration instance.

```
public class XDAO implements IXDAO {

//... snip

/* Get singleton */
public static synchronized XDAO getSingleton(){
   if (instance == null){
     instance = new XDAO(); // no configuration information is included!
   }       
  return instance;
}

/* constructor */
public XDAO(){
   initDatabase(); // this call needs db_name & host but you haven't set those yet!!
   initDatabaseIndexes();
}
```

I recommend you modify your application class to create XDAO along the lines of this:

```
@Override
public void run(final MongoConfiguration configuration, final Environment environment) {

  XDAO XDAOsingleton = new XDAO(configuration);
  XDAO.setSingletonInstance(XDAOsingleton); // You need to create this static method.

  final MyResource resource = new MyResource(configuration.getDb_name(), configuration.getMongohost(), configuration.getMongoport()); // MyResource depends on XDAO so must be created after XAO's singleton is set
  environment.jersey().register(resource);
}
```

You may also need to take `initDatabase()` etc out of XDAO's constructor depending on if you keep `public static synchronized XDAO getSingleton()`

I also recommend you change the constructor of `MyResource` to `public MyResource(XDAO xdao)`. The resource class doesn't appear to need the configuration information, and it is better to make the dependency on an XDAO explicit (you then also don't need to keep the XDAO singleton in a static field inside XDAO's class).

Answer (score 0):

To get MongoDB integrated in a simple way to Dropwizard, please try and use **MongoDB Managed Object**. I will explain this in 3 simple steps:

Step 1: Create a simple MongoManged class:

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import io.dropwizard.lifecycle.Managed;

public class MongoManaged implements Managed {

private Mongo mongo;

public MongoManaged(Mongo mongo) {
    this.mongo = mongo;
}

@Override
public void start() throws Exception {
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    mongo.close();
}
}
```

Step 2: Mention MongoDB Host, Port, DB Name in a config yml file:

```
mongoHost : localhost
mongoPort : 27017
mongoDB : softwaredevelopercentral
```

Step 3: Bind everything together in the Application Class:

```
public class DropwizardMongoDBApplication extends Application<DropwizardMongoDBConfiguration> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DropwizardMongoDBApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new DropwizardMongoDBApplication().run("server", args[0]);
}

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<DropwizardMongoDBConfiguration> b) {
}

@Override
public void run(DropwizardMongoDBConfiguration config, Environment env)
        throws Exception {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(config.getMongoHost(), config.getMongoPort());
    MongoManaged mongoManaged = new MongoManaged(mongoClient);
    env.lifecycle().manage(mongoManaged);
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(config.getMongoDB());
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(config.getCollectionName());
    logger.info("Registering RESTful API resources");
    env.jersey().register(new PingResource());
    env.jersey().register(new EmployeeResource(collection, new MongoService()));
    env.healthChecks().register("DropwizardMongoDBHealthCheck",
            new DropwizardMongoDBHealthCheckResource(mongoClient));
}
}
```

I have used these steps and written a blog post and a sample working application code is available on GitHub. Please check: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2017/09/dropwizard-mongodb-tutorial.html